# Evaluate $\lim\limits_{x \to -3^+} ((\ln(x+3))x^2-9\ln|2x+6|.$

Tags: limits

I have a limit problem I can't solve.

> Evaluate
>   $$\lim\limits_{x \to -3^+} (\ln(x+3))x^2-9\ln|2x+6|$$

When I want to solve it by plugging in the value I get $$\infty-\infty$$ which is undetermined. Does somebody know a way to solve this limit / or can somebody give me a hint on how to solve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try rewriting the offending expression. Remember that $\ln a - \ln b = \ln (\frac{a}{b})$.

Comment: is it $x^2\{\ln (x+3)\} \text{ or } \ln \{x^2(x+3)\} ?$

Comment: It is the first one, I'll change it to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $y=x+3$ so we want$$\lim_{y\to0^+}((y-3)^2\ln y-9\ln(2y))=\lim_{y\to0}((y-6)\underbrace{y\ln y}_{\to0}-9\ln2)=-9\ln2.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

If $x>3$, then $$\ln|2x+6|=\ln(2)+\ln(x+3).$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Write it as:

$$
\ln \frac{(x+3)^{x^2}}{|2x+6|^9}
$$

Then work on the fraction .